# Blender Unpack deletes image files with duplicate filenames

Tags: texturing, export, image, packed-data, packing

[image]

Inside a packed .blend file, images with same name are shown with different numeric suffixes.  These come from files that have the same name but are in different paths in the filesystem.
example:
\..\someProject\textures\Adam\car\base color.png

\..\AnotherProject\textures\Beth\car\base color.png

\......\someOtherFolder\pelicans\base color.png

When unpacked, Blender only writes one of these images in the textures folder.  It "forgets" all the others.  Every material now points to this *one remaining file*.

\.\textures\base color.png

I want to be able to recover *all* of these files somehow, even if they are renamed /appended with numbers to make them unique.

I am aware of the unpack option "to original locations" but realize:  I may be unpacking into a filesystem that bears no resemblance to the one in place when the file was written.  Worse, if it's only similar, I will be introducing scattered and un-trackable folders and files back across a network that someone is trying to keep clean.  So, before it gets suggested, know that the "original locations" option is not viable.

---

I tried to recreated this problem: make two images with the same name but different folder, and import as images textures for two materials. The second image was renamed with a .001 suffix. Then i packed these two images into .blend file.
[image]

Below is my demo file, thanks @Harry McKenzie!

[image]

So is there any way to extract these renamed images? not "save them one by one" solution but something more efficent?

Comment: Hello and welcome! when you say "unpack resources", do you mean you have a blend file with these resources in it and then you do *File > External Data > Unpack Resources...* ? can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Why are suffixes after the file extension?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Hi! Thank you for you reply! Yes, it's an alone .blend file, but it seems too big or something blend-exchange.com show errors. So i made a simple demo to show the same problem. You may want to check it out :)

Comment: Yeah that is a good question by Duarte. Why do you have numbers after the extension? Did you generate those numbers or were they automatic? Anyhow it is still a bug and should be handled by Blender. I have reported a bug ticket here https://developer.blender.org/T100361

Comment: @niakouzuki can you give me the link where you downloaded the blend file with the packed **base color.png.XXX** files?

Comment: Here's what I discovered through testing:  
When you go to Unpack that .blend file, Blender will "forget" all but one of those files, effectively deleting them.  The materials that used the .001 or .009 versions listed in the interface will _all_ point to that one file.  Worse still, all of them will appear as expected in the viewport, since they are still data blocks in the current session.  If you reload or revert the .blend file, though, they are gone forever.

I'm testing Blender's viability when it comes to archiving projects and confirming their future use.

Comment: As workaround you can change the file name of each overlapping image before unpacking them. You can use the "Data API" display mode of the Outliner. Looks for the image and change the "filepath" value inside the "Packed Files" section. You can ignore the "File Name" value, it is not used when unpacking.